# ¿Como puedo abrir un calendario en un botón con otro botón diferente? Estoy utilizando jquery-datepicker

Tags: jquery-datepicker

1. En el código que tengo abre el calendario en el botón en el que se dio click, pero quiero que lo abra en donde se va a ver la modificación de la fecha

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( ".fecha, .abrir-calendario-arriba" ).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p><input type="submit" class="fecha" id="datepicker" value="Fecha"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" class="abrir-calendario-arriba" id="datepicker" value="Cambiar y abrir el calendario en el boton de arriba"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, debes cambiarle el ID, pues está repetido y, finalmente, hacer que cuando cliques en él, enseñe el que deseas. La idea sería algo así:

```
<p><input type="submit" class="abrir-calendario-arriba" id="datepicker_aux" value="Cambiar y abrir el calendario en el boton de arriba"></p>

<script>
   $("#datepicker_aux").click( function() {
       $("#datepicker").show();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono hacer esto

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .back{
        background: #000;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">


      $(function() {
          $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
          closeText: 'Cerrar', 
          prevText: 'Previo', 
          nextText: 'Próximo',

          monthNames: ['de Enero','de Febrero','de Marzo','de Abril','de Mayo','de Junio', 'de Julio','de Agosto','de Septiembre','de Octubre','de Noviembre','de Diciembre'],
          monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun', 'Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
          monthStatus: 'Ver otro mes', yearStatus: 'Ver otro año',
          dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
          dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
          dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
          dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy', firstDay: 0, 
          initStatus: 'Selecciona la fecha',
          isRTL: false
        };
          $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "-5Y", maxDate: "+0D" });
          $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('clip', 'auto');

              $("#open-datepicker").click(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
                $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: 0
                }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
                return false;
              });
      });

    </script>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    SELECCIONAR:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" id="datepicker" value="fecha">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="open-datepicker" value="cambiar fecha">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Por favor no olvides marcar como aceptada aquella respuesta que te dió la solución al problema expuesto